# Передача данных из одного контроллера в другой. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ui, делегаты

Задача на первый взгляд кажется простой: необходимо из одно контроллера передать информацию в другой. 
Контроллер 1 - ViewController имеет textField, значение которого по нажатию на кнопку передается в контроллер 2 - TableViewController.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью делегата, это необходимо для того, чтобы переданную информацию сразу же отобразить в таблице.

Код ViewController:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!
  var flag = false

  @IBOutlet weak var testMessageField: UITextField!
    var socket = SocketManager()
  weak var delegate: (Any & ChatViewControllerDelegate)? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sendMessageToTVC()
        SocketManager.socketInstance.socket.connect()

  }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

  @IBAction func sendingMessage (_ sender: Any ) {
    if testMessageField.text != "" {
                flag = true
                sendMessageToTVC()
                testMessageField.text = ""
    }

  }

  func sendMessageToTVC(){

    if flag == true {
      if self.delegate != nil {
        self.delegate?.writeMessage(testMessageField.text!)
      }
    }
  }
}

 protocol ChatViewControllerDelegate: class  {
      func writeMessage(_ text: String)
    }
```

Код TableViewController:

```
class ChatcTVC: UITableViewController, SocketManagerDelegate, ChatViewControllerDelegate {

private var chatcVC: ChatViewController?

 func writeMessage(_ text: String) {
    //
    print(text)
  }

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
      chatcVC = ChatViewController()
      chatcVC?.delegate = self
      chatcVC?.sendMessageToTVC()

    }
```

Остальной код не привожу. Проблемы с флагом нет, а вот метод, который в TableViewController не вызывается. Не понимаю в чем проблема

PS Реализация через prepare(forsegue). Также не работает, метод вызывается только при открытии приложения.

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if flag == true {
      var destination: ChatcTVC = segue.destination as! ChatcTVC
      destination.text = testMessageField.text!
      flag = false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Зачем для передачи во второй делегат? Задача, как Вы и написали, простая - используйте prepare(for:sender:)

Comment: Через prepare(for:sender:) не работает, данные метод вызывается только один раз при старте приложения, а далее он игнорируется

Comment: а, недосмотрел что у Вас embedded segue. Тогда берите контроллер в prepare и напрямую передавайте когда нужно данные

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит это: Тогда берите контроллер в prepare и напрямую передавайте когда нужно данные

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
weak var secondViewController: MySecondViewController?
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MyEmbeddedSegueIdentifier" {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? MySecondViewController {
            secondViewController = controller
        }
    }
}
func send(data: String) {
    secondViewController.someStringVar = data
}
```

Получаете второй контроллер в prepare и передаете данные

Comment: А где я укажу identifier?

Comment: @kylesp1995 в storyboard выберите segue и пропишите ей identifier

Comment: спасибо, завтра попробую, а пока еще вопрос, метод send нигде не нужно вызывать?

Comment: К сожалению, Ваш метод не работает, метод вызывается единожды, а мне нужно каждый раз, когда нажимается кнопка

Comment: @kylesp1995 что именно не работает? А зачем больше одного чтобы получить нужный контроллер?

Comment: так это по сути мессенджер, при вводе сообщения, пользователь нажимает на "отпр", а приложение почти моментально должно отобразить это в таблице. То есть я должен каждый раз передавать вводимое значение

Comment: func send(data: String) {
    secondViewController.someStringVar = data
}.   Эта функция же в контроллере 1? А какое взаимодействие в контроллере 2?